# Temp Table in SQL (Rows to Columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this in SQL:

```
Name                Price   
Ferrari White       1000            
350z Purple         540           
Lambo Black         2500
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to to create a temp table like this

```
Ferrari White     350z Purple       Lambo Black 
1000              540               2500
```

using a query.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I'm using this code:

```
select Firstname, Amount, PostalCode, LastName, AccountNumber
from
(
  select value, columnname
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for columnname in (Firstname, Amount, PostalCode, LastName, AccountNumber)
) piv;
```

But the problem I have is that the name of the rows have spaces like this 'Ferrari White' so in the query I got error because it isn't a one word name.

EDIT2: (SOLVED)

I used this method:

```
select
  max(case when columnname = 'FirstName' then value end) Firstname,
  max(case when columnname = 'Amount' then value end) Amount,
  max(case when columnname = 'PostalCode' then value end) PostalCode,
  max(case when columnname = 'LastName' then value end) LastName,
  max(case when columnname = 'AccountNumber' then value end) AccountNumber
from yourtable
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Tag the dbms used.

Comment: Did the link to the other question help you? If not, how's your question different?

Comment: Yes ti helped me, the first method didn't work but the second did thanks.

Comment: Great to hear you're back on the track! Have a nice weekend.