# SQL Query to turn my columns un to rows

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im looking for a way to make this happen:

From this:

```
  id   date    budget  forecast  actual
  0   1/1/111   100       200       5
  1   2/1/111   10        20        3
  2   3/1/111   300       5000      1
  3   4/1/111   400       800       0
```

To this:

```
column1    column2     column3  column4   column5 
id             0          1        2         3       
date       1/11/1111 2/11/1111 3/11/1111 4/11/1111
budget        100         10       300        400
forecast       200        20       5000        800
actual         5          3          1          0
```

Is there any way of doing this in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38146290/1070452

Comment: Please Tag your RDMS